# Trust based dictionary

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph-algorithm

Lets say we have a system with a number of "users". Each of those users can have their own "key/value" dictionary.

Let say we store this data in a dictionary itself, `data`, with key `(user, key)` and value `value`.

Also, users can trust other users. Lets say we store this in `trust`, with key `user` and value which is an ordered array of users that user trusts.

Lets say "Alice" trusts "Bob" the most, but then "Chris".

So we store in `trust`: "Alice": ["Bob", "Chris"]

I then want a function `get`, which works like the following:

```
get(user, key)
  if (data.haskey((user, key)) then
     return data.get((user,key))
  else
     trusted_users = trust.get(user)
     for (trusted_user in trusted_users)
       result = get(trusted_user, key)
       if (result is not null)
         return result
     return null
   end if
```

In plain English, if I've got the key in my store, return it's value. If not, check my most trusted friend (and anyone who they trust, and so on). If not, then check my next most trusted friend and so on. If none of my friends are friends (or friends of friends etc) of someone who has this key, then return that it's not found.

I've given a trivial implementation to explain my problem, however it won't scale well, as due to the recursion it's quite possible it execution time increases linearly with the number of users.

I'm looking for a better data design and algorithm which scales better.

Comment: Well if u want to scale the problem better u gotto use additional storage that will give extra information and reduce processing. For eg keeping a list of visited nodes. Thus if a friend is encountered twice then the friend's list of trusted friend will not be traversed.

Comment: If A trust B , can we assume that B trust A ??

Comment: In your example implementation, I don't see you checking for "Friends of Friends". However, in your subsequent explanation, you seem to mention checking for friends of friends. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

The code presented is worse than linear, because it is possible to visit friends A-B-C and then A-C-B, if A, B, and C, are all friends. In the recursive friend search you should keep a set of friends visited so far, and not recurse through a friend you have already visited. You would have to pass a pointer to this set through as part of the recursive call to get it updated properly.

If values in the map do not change and keys may be accessed again, you could keep a copy of key-value pairs from friends to save bothering them again.

Comment: Yes, I know the code presented is bad. Indeed it can get stuck in loops. But like I said, it's just to illustrate the problem, it's not a solution (if it was I wouldn't be asking the question).